# Elite Dangerous: Resource Extraction Sites

Tags: elite-dangerous, elite-dangerous-horizons

I've been away from Elite Dangerous for about a year now, and pretty pleased with all of the new updates and content.

However I'm searching for resource extraction sites, and they no longer seem to show up in system maps or just super cruising around a system. All of the links that had listings for the sites no longer seem valid.

Does anyone know if this feature of the game has changed? I've been reading through the patch notes and game updates but haven't found anything yet.

The resource extraction sites were a juicy place for bounty hunting as well as scooping up free floating cargo. Either I'm just looking in the wrong places or they changed this part of the gameplay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I'll answer your question about the change: a lot of players report that RES are very rare since the extension "Horizon" was released. Knowing that, players have found ways to still find places for bounty hunting.

### EDDB

I usually use [EDDB](https://eddb.io) to find quickly what I need. Its database is huge. In the "system" tab, you can find any system, with several filters, like the reference system (where you are), or the primary economy (such as Extraction).

Then you can find the best spots for your activity / your way of enjoying the game, whatever way it is.

### Hozbase

Another useful tool is [Hozbase](http://www.hozbase.co.uk/elitedangerous): here you can find a list of Compromised Beacon and Hazardous RES (ressource extraction sites), maintained by [a player, mr.Gr3y](https://forums.frontier.co.uk/showthread.php?t=241871) . The last updates are respectively on 06/29 and 06/16 of 2017, so pretty accurate.

You have two filters to narrow down the results: your base system (called target system on the site) and the maximum range of search (in Ly).